# Average length of confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval

For a particular sample, the small value of this length indicate greater confidence  but in many research articles, authors report average length of Confidence interval based on simulation study. Why is the average of CI length (UB-LB) calculated? What is the significance of it?

Comment: There are many kinds of confidence intervals for various parameters. So, for a specific answer, you should specify what data, what distribution, what parameter, and what style of CI. // There are two goals for a satisfactory C(: (a) it should have the promised coverage probability (say 95%) over the long run, (b) it should be as short as possible consistent with the available data.// Sometimes the mean length can be derived analytically, but sometimes (as for certain nonparametric CIs) an analytic solution is messy or elusive, and then you can use simulation to get an good approximate result.

Comment: For example, it can be assumed that I am calculating classical CI with 95% confidence level and variance known. So, if I repeatedly draw samples of same size and calculate CI each time. I can then take average of such CI lengths. If I have to compare two estimators (say t1, t2 ; rest being the same) based on the average lengths of CIs, then if we get smaller Average CI length for t1, then we would prefer t1. So, what is the logic behind this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow the logic of your Comment. 95% CI for normal mean $\mu$ is $\bar X \pm 1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ of fixed length $3.92\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}},$ where $\sigma$ and $n$ are both known. There is nothing further to compute, estimate, or simulate. // Similarly, the length of a 95% t CI for $\mu$ is $2t^*\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}},$ where $t^*$ cuts probability 0.025 from upper tail of $\mathsf{T}(df=n-1).$ Here $t^*$ is known and so expected length of the CI is $2t^*E(S)/\sqrt{n}.$ // Pls give a _specific_ instance in which you have seen simulation used. Then something to discuss.